# Laravel Broadcasting To Private Channel Fails

Tags: laravel, websocket, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

I'm using Redis to broadcast messages to a private channel but getting the following error whenever the event is initiated

```
 Class 'App\Events\PrivateChannel' not found
```

I made sure to import

```
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
```

But still nothing. Public channels worked successfully before that. Why would it not find PrivateChannel though? Kind of got me stumped.

My broadcastOn method in my event

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('invitation.' . $this->message->to);
}
```

The full event

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;

class ProfileInvited implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public $message;

    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->dontBroadcastToCurrentUser();
    }

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('invitation.' . $this->message->to);
    }
}
```

Comment: try composer dumpautoload in console

Comment: Still same error :/

Comment: Make sure the namespace is correct at the top. If not, share your full code of file and flle path in directory with us

Comment: Hello, I double checked the namespace and it seems to be correct. I updated the question with the full event. Path to the event is app/Events/ProfileInvited.php

Comment: Try `php artisan optimize` maybe